Move the equation to left side inside split environment
Question:
Is it possible to shift the entire equation to left side? Because when I am using split alignment inside the equation, it centers in the middle of the page.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[width=1.00in, height=0.80in, left=0.80in, right=0.80in, top=0.80in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
            u\;\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\;\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
            &=  u_{e}\;\dfrac{d \,u_{e}}{d\, x}+\dfrac{\mu \left(1+\frac{1}{\gamma}\right)}{\rho}\,\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} -\dfrac{\sigma B_{0}^{2}}{\rho}\,\left(u_{e}-u\right)
            -\frac{\mu\,\phi}{\rho k'}\,\left(u_{e}-u\right)
            \\[1ex]
            &\qquad\qquad\quad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad + g\;\beta_{T}\;(T-T_{\infty})\,+ g\;\beta_{C}\;(C-C_{\infty})
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}


Off-topic: The geometry package options width=1.00in and height=0.80in are incompatible with the other options (left, right, top, bottom, and paper size).

Environment split  align its content at split markers -- ampersands. Whole equation is centered by equation environment. Do you like that all equation istart at left border or just this one? Please clarify.

I guess you want multline.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  %width=1.00in,
  %height=0.80in, 
  left=0.80in,
  right=0.80in,
  top=0.80in,
  bottom=1.00in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{multline}
u\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
  = u_{e}\,\frac{du_{e}}{dx}
  + \frac{\mu \bigl(1+\frac{1}{\gamma}\bigr)}{\rho}\,\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
  - \frac{\sigma B_{0}^{2}}{\rho}\,(u_{e}-u)
  - \frac{\mu\phi}{\rho k'}\,(u_{e}-u)
\\[1ex]
  + g\beta_{T}(T-T_{\infty}) +  g\beta_{C}(C-C_{\infty})
\end{multline}

\end{document}

Note that I removed all \; commands and also all \left and \right directives. You get very unequal spacings. I only left \, in order to separate fractions.

Of course, width=1in and height=0.8in are meaningless. I'm not sure why using inches in a metric context (A4 paper).

Once again, thank you so much. You are not the answer to my question, it clears up my silly mistakes.


Because when I am using split alignment inside the equation, it centers in the middle of the page.

The LaTeX default is to center-set all displayed equations -- not just the ones that contain a split environment. If you want to override this default, I suggest you specify the document class option fleqn (short for "flush-left equations").
I would also get rid of the \; spacers, all \qquad directives in the second row, and all \left and \right auto-sizing directives. I further suggest you replace 1+\frac{1}{\gamma} in the upper row with 1+1/\gamma, in order to obtain a better visual balance across the rows.
Incidentally, if you want to right-align the row contents within a given split environment, there's no need for \qquad\qquad\quad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad. Instead, just omit the & alignment specifiers in both rows. See the second equation below for the resulting "look".

The vertical lines at the edges of the screenshot are drawn because the code loads the geometry package with the option showframe. You will probably want to omit this option in your real document.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article} % note the 'fleqn' option
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.8in, top=0.8in, bottom=1in,
            showframe % delete this option in real document
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
       u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
      +v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
   &=  u_{e}\frac{d u_{e}}{d x}
      +\frac{\mu (1+1/\gamma)}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} 
      -\frac{\sigma B_{0}^{2}}{\rho}(u_{e}-u)
      -\frac{\mu\phi}{\rho k'}(u_{e}-u)
   \\[\jot]
   &\quad +g\beta_{T}(T-T_{\infty})
          +g\beta_{C}(C-C_{\infty})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
       u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
      +v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
    =  u_{e}\frac{d u_{e}}{d x}
      +\frac{\mu (1+1/\gamma)}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} 
      -\frac{\sigma B_{0}^{2}}{\rho}(u_{e}-u)
      -\frac{\mu\phi}{\rho k'}(u_{e}-u)
   \\[\jot]
        {}+g\beta_{T}(T-T_{\infty})
          +g\beta_{C}(C-C_{\infty})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Thank you so much for your help.  Your answer is also useful. Suggestions are also useful for future work.

@SandyM, this is answer solve and explain problem  mentioned in your question. You should accept it ...
